# Laravel 7: How to match today date with database date?

Tags: datetime, count, laravel-7

I want to count all the records which match with today date.

My Code:

```
$today_present = \App\Attendance::where('attendance_date', '=',  Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString())
                    ->where('attendance_status', 1)->get();
    $today_absent = \App\Attendance::where('attendance_date', '=',  Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString())
                    ->where('attendance_status', 0)->get();
```

Here I want to count today present and absent row from the table. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hi Please Use this it will work:

$StartDate=date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');//Also you can change date formate according your save date like Y-m-d or d-m-Y etc.

$EndDate=date('Y-m-d 23:59:59');

$today_present = \App\Attendance::whereBetween('attendance_date', [$StartDate, $EndDate])
->where('attendance_status', 1)->get();
$today_absent = \App\Attendance::whereBetween('attendance_date', [$StartDate, $EndDate])
->where('attendance_status', 0)->get();

Answer (score 0):

### also, you can import your modal name in the header and just use your a modal name like :

$today_present = Attendance::whereBetween('attendance_date', [$StartDate, $EndDate]) ->where('attendance_status', 1)->get();